# Display RadioGroup in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to know how can I put a RadioGroup in a ListView?

I am a beginner at developing android.

What should I do to display the RadioGroup in the ListView.
Please guide me.

This is my code:

```
enter code here
package com.mySample.Smpl1;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.app.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Smpl1 extends ListActivity
 {


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     final String[] row = new  String []{"row1","row2"};
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.radiolayout,
             row));



     ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  

     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
     {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View eview,int position,long id)
         {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)eview).getText(),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

         }

     });



   }
}
```

and this is my rowylayout.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="hahaha">`

     </TextView>



enter code here
```

my radio.xml

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>
   </RadioGroup>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to put a radio group in one row or all your rows having single radio button and you want to make them in a radiogroup...

Comment: @BharatSharma, I want to put radio group in one row in list view,thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:baselineAligned="false" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"/>
```

this code should come inside rowylayout.xml file which is the list item

Comment: can you show me how can i call that in Class smlp1 because it throws exception,and i could not determine what is the cause for the error.

Comment: but removing the TextView tag in rowlayout and replace it with the RadioGroup,The application screen will force to close.it will generate error.can you help me please on this.

Comment: use listview and for list view prepare one adapter class that will populate you custom list Item having you radio group

for help try this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: but how can i call that in my class smpl1?